# How to check if we have a specific file uri permission on Android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have this situation:

- User chooses an image from a gallery while app has the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` granted, and the path goes something like `content://media/external/images...`
- User leaves the app and image path is saved in a bundle in case user comes back.
- User revokes the permission and comes back to the app. I try to restore path from the bundle but by accessing it I cause a crash:

  > java.lang.SecurityException: *** has no access to content://media/external/images...

I can check if the app has the permission, but there is a pretty good chance that the path did not require the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the first place (maybe user did not revoke the permission, maybe they never allowed it), and it could have been displayed.
Is there a way to check if my app has permission for a specific file?

I tried this but it seems that's not what it's for, it always returns false:

```
context.checkCallingUriPermission()
```

Comment: `User revokes the permission` ? I have no idea what that would be.

Comment: Start with telling which action used to get that uri.

Comment: @blackapps revokes the permission = goes into settings of the phone and sets the storage permission of our app to unselected. We get the uri with `val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT) intent.type = "image/*"`

Comment: That user action has no effect on action get content. An uri/permission obtained with action get content only last for a short while and is gone certainly after app restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user pick a file.

Then in onActivityResult() take persistable uri permission.

After that you can save data.getData().toString() to shared preferences and reuse after app restart.

This all has nothing to do with a read external storage permission.

You can also request Android OS for a list of persistable uries of your app.

Comment: useful explanation in case someone needs it: [Data storage docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) 
[SAF](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html)